# SQLite: Fsyncing with journal_mode = wal and synchronous = normal

Tags: linux, sqlite

I have an interesting issue using SQLite 3.7.13 on Debian 7.

I'm using SQLite with "PRAGMA journal_mode = wal" and "PRAGMA synchronous = normal" to try and avoid fsyncs in the main event loop of a Python program. As suggested by the documentation I have disabled automatic checkpoints and I am periodically running "PRAGMA wal_checkpoint" in a **different thread** to sync the most recent data to disk.

This is working however I have found that the **first** insert operation after a checkpoint in the **main program thread** is causing a one-off fsync call for the WAL file itself. Any further insert operations do not cause an fsync. I have verified this using strace.

Looking at the SQLite docs it says:

> WAL file header is synchronized when a WAL file begins to be reused after a checkpoint

I'm looking for a way to prevent any fsyncs occurring in the main thread, but that still allows me to perform periodic checkpoints from another thread. Is there something more that can be done in the check point thread to avoid the fsync in the main thread?

I have looked at "synchronous = off", however that also blocks the fsyncs for the checkpoints.

Note: I have a separate connection to the database for each of the two threads (in case that is relevant)

Further note: the documentation seems to say elsewhere that there shouldn't be an fsync, but observed behavior obviously differs:

> Note that with PRAGMA synchronous set to NORMAL, the checkpoint is the only operation to issue an I/O barrier or sync operation (fsync() on unix or FlushFileBuffers() on windows). If an application therefore runs checkpoint in a separate thread or process, the main thread or process that is doing database queries and updates will never block on a sync operation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To move that fsync into the other thread, do the first operation that changes the database in that thread.
You can use something harmless like `PRAGMA user_version = 42` (assuming you don't use the [user version](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_schema_version)).

Comment: This does appear to be a valid work-around (I've tested it in my scenario) however I was hoping for something which could guarantee that main thread would never end up calling fsync, I'm assuming here that there is a small chance that the main thread could hit the database between the calls to "PRAGMA wal_checkpoint" and "PRAGMA user_version = 42" in the other thread.